# How to get the working directory in executor

Tags: apache-spark, spark-streaming

I am using the following command to submit Spark job, I hope to send jar and config files to each executor and load it there

```
spark-submit --verbose \
--files=/tmp/metrics.properties \ 
--jars /tmp/datainsights-metrics-source-assembly-1.0.jar \ 
--total-executor-cores 4\
--conf "spark.metrics.conf=metrics.properties" \
--conf "spark.executor.extraClassPath=datainsights-metrics-source-assembly-1.0.jar"  \
--class org.microsoft.ofe.datainsights.StartServiceSignalPipeline \
./target/datainsights-1.0-jar-with-dependencies.jar
```

--files and --jars is used to send files to executors, I found that the files are sent to the working directory of executor like 'worker/app-xxxxx-xxxx/0/

But when job is running, the executor always throws exception saying that it could not find the file 'metrics.properties'or the class which is contained in 'datainsights-metrics-source-assembly-1.0.jar'. It seems that the job is looking for files under another dir rather than working directory.

Do you know how to load the file which is sent to executors?

Here is the trace (The class 'org.apache.spark.metrics.PerfCounterSource' is contained in the jar 'datainsights-metrics-source-assembly-1.0.jar'):

```
ERROR 2016-01-14 16:10:32 Logging.scala:96 - org.apache.spark.metrics.MetricsSystem: Source class org.apache.spark.metrics.PerfCounterSource cannot be instantiated
java.lang.ClassNotFoundException: org.apache.spark.metrics.PerfCounterSource
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:366) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.net.URLClassLoader$1.run(URLClassLoader.java:355) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [na:1.7.0_80]
at java.net.URLClassLoader.findClass(URLClassLoader.java:354) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:425) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at sun.misc.Launcher$AppClassLoader.loadClass(Launcher.java:308) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.ClassLoader.loadClass(ClassLoader.java:358) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.Class.forName0(Native Method) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
at java.lang.Class.forName(Class.java:195) ~[na:1.7.0_80]
```

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you have a typo in your --jars argument, so it could be that it's not actually loading the file and and continuing silently.

Comment: But what about the file metrics.properties? It is also unable to be found. Also, I corrected the typo and it still does not work

Comment: Could you share more information, perhaps the output of the logs from spark-submit?

Comment: Could you share the full log? Spark is actually pretty verbose with it's logging by default, which means you can see messages about JARs being shipped (or not, if that's a concern) and probably similar for files. If there's a reason it's not being shipped it's probably in the log.

Comment: but it is not the answer